# Eager loading with HQL

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Is it possible to do eager loading with HQL without touching mappings? The "left join fetch" expression is completely ignored by nHibernate.

```
var query = Session.CreateQuery("from o in Member left join fetch o.Photos");
query.List<Member>();
```

The generated SQL is

```
SELECT this_.Id as Id7_1_, this_.Name as Name7_1_, this_.AltNames as AltNames7_1_,
this_.Tags as Tags7_1_, this_.Loved as Loved7_1_, profile2_.id as id6_0_,
profile2_.Website as Website6_0_, profile2_.Email as Email6_0_, 
profile2_.Shop as Shop6_0_ 
FROM Member this_ 
left outer join member_profile profile2_ on this_.Id=profile2_.id 
limit 10;
```

And then 10 statements grabbing the photos. MemberProfile is mapped as OneToOne.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`fetch`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) keyword:

```
from Cat as cat inner join fetch cat.Mate
```

This will eagerly load the `Mate` association.

Comment: It just completely ignores the "join fetch" part.

Comment: How about a left join: `from Cat as cat left join cat.Kittens`?

Comment: I've updated the question. Any type of join fetch is ignored.

Comment: You HQL syntax is strange. Try this: `from Member as m left join fetch m.Photos`

Comment: I've figured it out, there was some other bug in my code. Still thanks for the answer, good to know.

Comment: I've sorted my code. Now nHibernate ignores SetMaxResults if I use your query and grabs everything from the database.